# Access Timeline user token for callback from GDK LiveCard Action or Event

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

If I have a LiveCard created by the GDK. Can I access the UserToken used in Subscription callbacks from Mirror to invoke authenticated services and actions from the LiveCard as I would with an ordinary Timeline Item.  If not what its he best practice for authenticating user actions from a LiveCard as compared with a TimelineItem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. I recommend against depending on it too much, though. A better solution is around the corner.

Along with the GDK sneak peek, the Glass team announced that an authentication flow is in the works. It will allow you to specify an auth credential via a web service which is then made available to your GDK Glassware from the android AccountManager.